# Wildcard overwrites all other settings

Tags: css, wildcard, overwrite

I'm new to CSS. The tutorials taught me, that settings defined in the upper part of the css file are overwritten by the settings defined below. Now I try to create a custom cursor for my whole page, which is animated while clicking on a link. My code looks like this:

```
* {
    cursor:    url("../dartpfeil.cur"), auto;
}

...

.menu a:active {
    cursor:    url("../dartpfeil_steckt.cur"), auto;
}
```

But this doesn't work. The cursor defined in the * section works, but if I click on the menu link, the cursor doesn't change. If I delete the * section and add the following code:

```
.menu a:hover {
    cursor:    url("../dartpfeil.cur"), auto;
}
```

it works, but the "dartpfeil.cur" cursor is only shown by hovering the links. I also tried

```
*:hover {
    cursor:    url("../dartpfeil.cur"), auto;
}
```

but then the cursor is also only shown by hovering a link. I want to use the "dartpfeil.cur" on the whole page as if it is defined in *, but i want also the "dartpfeil_steckt.cur" while link is active. Is there any possible solution for this problem?

Thanks and a **happy new year to all!**

**EDIT:** Error in code fixed 
**EDIT2:** As asked, the html code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dartverein XY</title>        

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
        <a href="index.php" id="headerLink">
            <section id="header">
                <div id="title">Steeldartverein<br>M&uuml;hldorf e.V.</div>     
            </section>
        </a>

        <div class="horizontalBorder"></div>

        <section class="menu">
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div class="menuElementRed">News</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div class="menuElementGreen">&Uuml;ber uns</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div class="menuElementRed">Weiteres</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div class="menuElementGreen">Login</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <p class="lastVerticalBorder"></p>
        </section>

        <div class="horizontalBorder"></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the markup you use for this

Comment: Also, what do you mean by active link?

Comment: @LGSon a link is active (catched by css selector ":active"), if the cursor is on the link and the left mouse button is pressed. I added the HTML code to the question.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

Why it does not work is because it is your `div` that is the *active* element and for a `div` to respond to the `:active` class it need `tabindex`.

I added `tabindex` (and an extra CSS rule) to/for the *News* link `div` so you see how that work, and I also removed the `div` on the *Über uns* link and now that one work too

```css
* {
    cursor:    url("../dartpfeil.cur"), auto;
  color: lime;
}
.menu a:active {
    cursor:    url("../dartpfeil_steckt.cur"), auto;
  color: red;
}
.menu a div:active {
  cursor:    url("../dartpfeil_steckt.cur"), auto;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dartverein XY</title>        

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
        <a href="index.php" id="headerLink">
            <section id="header">
                <div id="title">Steeldartverein<br>M&uuml;hldorf e.V.</div>     
            </section>
        </a>

        <div class="horizontalBorder"></div>

        <section class="menu">
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div tabindex="0" class="menuElementRed">News</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href="">&Uuml;ber uns</a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div class="menuElementRed">Weiteres</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <a href=""><div class="menuElementGreen">Login</div></a>
            <p class="verticalBorder"></p>
            <p class="lastVerticalBorder"></p>
        </section>

        <div class="horizontalBorder"></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "dartpfeil_steckt.cur" work for *? Your code looks fine, and it should override the wildcard because it's more specific. My best guess is that you have misplaced the file, or misspelled the filename.

Comment: Sadly yes. If i replace the * by ".menu a:hover" it works, but then (logically) the "dartpfeil.cur" is only shown by hovering links.